# Reversing an inswing door to an outswing door?

Tags: insulation, doors

I about to tear out and rebuild a portion of an exterior wall in which I will be installing a door, is it possible since it's new construction to purchase and inswing door and convert it to an outswing door?

Thanks

Comment: You should consider that an out swinging exterior door will significantly decrease security because your hinges will now be exposed.

Comment: NRP (non-removable pin) hinges are specified for outswing. And yes, someone could take a grinder to them and defeat the pin, but if someone has time to do that, the adjacent window would be the first target. Outswing doors are more resistant to being kicked in, fwiw.

Comment: relevant question here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/77587/can-i-convert-door-slab-from-lh-inswing-to-rh-inswing

Comment: I was hoping I could swap out the hinges for the security hinges.

Comment: You can also use "jamb pins" or "hinge pins" -- even if someone takes a grinder to the hinge, the door won't open.  Here's a picture:  http://www.solonsecurity.co.uk/assets/images/products/medium/BD0503HingeBoltsACTION.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think I just answered my own question, I understand that an outswing door can be purchased in the local box stores. I was under the misunderstanding that they were a costly online purchase.

Comment: The prehungs from big box stores that I've worked with have pretty much always been a little disappointing. (Hinge screws driven on angle, jamb cut  faintly wrong, etc.) Functional, though. You'd probably do better (and not much more expensive) with a door from a specialty supplier.

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible, but why don't you just purchase an outswing door?

If you flip the door frame, the threshold will slant inward instead of outward.

Good luck!

Comment: I've not found an outswing door in store, they seem to be online purchase and a bit more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If you're keeping the same door frame, you'll need to change the placement of the hinges, door latch and door stop; just reverse everything. Depending on the materials of the frame, you can likely putty the old holes, sand them, and refinish the surface.

Comment: Not keeping the same door and door frame, I'll be purchasing a prehung.